# Why Java fail to run class- error occurred during initialization of boot layer- Module mods not found

Tags: java, java-9

I have gone through the [java 9 jigsaw tutorial](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start). I have been struggling to run class, java throws below error-

```
java --module-path mods -m mods/com.test/com.test.HelloWorld
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module mods not found
```

Javac command-

```
javac -d mods --module-source-path src $(find src -name '*.java')
```

I am using mac, java version-

```
$ java -version
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove additional mods from module name-

```
java --module-path mods -m com.test/com.test.HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 3):

The `-m` flag accepts the module name and the main class you want to run. The module name is `com.test`, hence the command to run the class should be:

```
java --module-path mods -m com.test/com.test.HelloWorld
```

The `--module-path mods` tells `java` where to search for to find `com.test`.

Answer (score 2):

When you first compiled your code using [`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#JSWOR627) command as-

```
javac -d mods --module-source-path src $(find src -name '*.java')
```

What you ensured using `-d directory` was that to

> Set the destination directory for class files.

in your case the `mods` folder where

> If a class is part of a package, then javac puts the class file in a
>   subdirectory that reflects the package name and creates directories as
>   needed.

Hence you can take a look at the mods directory after executing the command, the `.class` for all(`*.java`) would exist in the corresponding directory structure as of their package name.

---

Then [`java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624) tool option `--module-path module path` or `-p module path` specified in your next command :

> Searches for directories from a semicolon-separated (;) list of
>   directories. Each directory is a directory of modules.

Your listed directory according to which is `mods`, assuming which you must have created following the getting started link.

---

Followed by `--module modulename[/mainclass]` or `-m module[/mainclass]` in your command

> Specifies the initial module to resolve and the name of the main class to execute if not specified by the module.

which in your case is the module name `com.test` and the main class `com.test.HelloWorld`.

---

Hence the complete correct syntax of the command shall be:-

```
java --module-path mods    -m     com.test/com.test.HelloWorld
                   ^               ^         ^
           module directory  module name   main class
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info

2 things I was doing incorrectly

1) Using the package path again like below

module\package\package.class

We should not retype the package path while executing the class.

2) Using the dos styled backslash instead of forward slash. We should always use the forward slash (/) to separate module with the class even you are executing in windows environment.

module/package.class